# Determining the sample rate of a large audio file in javascript?

Tags: web-audio-api

In javascript, I am converting mp3 data in the form of an array buffer into an object URL with `window.URL.createObjectURL` ... how could I determine the sample rate of the mp3 file?

I could use the web audio API to load the samples of the audio into memory, but the mp3 file is 300MB ...

Can the web audio API determine the sample rate of an audio element without creating an `AudioBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Range` header to return enough bytes to read the `sampleRate`. This still creates an `AudioBuffer` but the whole file is not downloaded.

```
var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://example.com/file.mp3';
req.open('GET', url);
req.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-640'); // enough bytes to read meta data
req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
req.onload = function(event) {
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(this.response, function(decodedBuffer) {
    console.log(decodedBuffer.sampleRate);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
req.send();
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/oxv5ykvn/**

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  decodeAudioData always resamples the result to the sample rate of the audio context.  However, see also https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/30